# Assigning javascript code to a variable and executing it

Tags: javascript, html

i have been trying to assign a code line to a variable but i don't know how to execute the variable in javascript.

```
<html>
<body>
 <div id='on'>change background color</div>
 <script>
  var x =  "document.getElementById('on').style.backgroundColor='red';";
  //here i want to execute the variable x to change the backgroundcolor for id 'on'.   
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you need to define the js code as a string?

Comment: Wrap it into function like var x = function(){document.getElement...} and remove the double quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript has [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval):

```js
var x =  "document.getElementById('on').style.backgroundColor='red';";
eval(x);
```

```html
<div id='on'>change background color</div>
```

Comment: Thank you bro. i searched this result for a long time but now i got the right one.

Comment: Eval is really unsafe especially if he takes user input some how.

Comment: @DaCurse yeah, I had a bet that some crusader comes up with this nonsense. There is no safety (for the site) on *client side*, the user can type *absolutely anything* into the developer console.

Answer (score 1):

Use an anonymous function instead of a string:

```js
let x = function() {
  document.getElementById('on').style.backgroundColor = 'red';
};

x();
```

```html
<div id='on'>change background color</div>
```

Comment: bro i just want to know how to execute a variable like we print a variable in c programs (i.e. int a =5; printf("%d",a);). and anyway Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: You can't "execute" a variable, you can set it to a function and execute the function.